# enabling https for sub domain

Tags: apache, https

We have a application with its domain and subdomain running on the same server.We need to configure domain and sub-domain as https.We can able to access the main domain via https,when the subdomain is accessed the connection is not secured. How to access the sub-domains as https?

Comment: Those are separate virtual hosts in the apache http server. That means you need to separate ssl (https) separately for each host. You can either use separate ssl certificates or a single multi name certificate or wildcard certificate, you only need to take care that each host is using a certificate that matches its host name (called "domain" and "subdomain" by you).

Comment: @arkascha pretty complete comment, imho the wildcard cert is the most reusable one.